# Angular (ng-grid) binding to WebApi results

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, ng-grid

I am stuck on why I cannot get my Angular grid (ng-grid) to display data coming back from my OData feed.

OData feed is using WebAPI and EntityFramework and is returning data just fine all the way to the client.

I have tried making sure I am using the CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver in my WebApiConfig.cs

```
var jsonFormatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

I have also tried parsing the return result on the client to an array on success in the Angular controller.

```
 $scope.serverData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Any thoughts?

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module("WorksheetApp", ['ngResource', 'ngGrid']);
app.controller('WorksheetController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'serverData'
};
function fetchData() {
    $http({ url: '/odata/CommitteeWorksheets', type: 'Get' })
        .success(function (data) { $scope.serverData = data; });
    }
    fetchData();
});
```

Note: All of this code works if I pass a hardcoded array the data parameter for the grid so the page is setup to display the grid as well.

Thanks!!
Ed

Comment: Shouldn't be "fetchData()" outside of "function fetchData()"? Uh, I see it is! Just got the formating wrong. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData returns an object containing the results of query, as well as metadata. ng-grid is just looking for the objects to display in the grid, so you need this code in your callback:

```
$scope.serverData = data.value;
```

Comment: Thanks Travis, this is exactly what was missing. Works like a charm. Also as you pointed out in another conversation the line $scope.serverData = JSON.parse(data); is not needed. I tried that just for troubleshooting.